# Can "-ness" be added to any adjective?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes, derivational-morphology, derivation

My friend and I have recently engaged in a little argument. It came about when he used the word "suaveness" and I argued that it wasn't a word. While I will concede he was right in this example, he made the claim that he could put "-ness" on the end of any adjective.

I do not believe this to be true.

Words like "fastestness" or "sleepingness" don't sit well with me. Are these words? If they are, are there any examples that don't work?

I also brought up "polyesterness" as an example, but he won't concede that "polyester" could be considered an adjective.

Comment: No. Suffixes like _-ness, -dom, -hood, -ship,_ etc, which form nouns, are **Derivational** affixes, and derivational affixes do not normally apply to entire word classes  like "adjective". Rather, there is a special list of words which require each one, and you have to learn them individually, like prepositions after verbs. It's the [**Inflectional** affixes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) that apply to entire word classes, but the only English inflectional affixes that apply to adjectives are comparative and superlative.

Comment: You are cheating, of course. *Fastest* is a superlative, and *sleeping* is a present participle. So of course *fastestness* and *sleepingness* don't sit with you anywhere as well as *fastness* and *sleepiness* would. That being said, of course *fastestness* and *sleepingness* are words. What else are they?

Comment: _-ness_ can only productively be added to non-inflected forms of true adjectives. ‘Fastest’ is the superlative, so adding _-ness_ does not really work (‘fastness’ does, though); and ‘sleeping’ is a participle, not a true adjective.

Comment: @RegDwigнt "What else are they". I'm not sure if I can accept that line of reasoning. They could be nonsense. I could use the same line of reasoning and say: "of course 'feawfeaw' is a word. What else is it?"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are superlatives considered adjectives or no?

Comment: And you would be right. "Feawfeaw" *is* a word. What is *your* line of reasoning that it isn't? Your editing your question to include it is precisely what I'm aiming at.

Comment: BTW just for the record, contrary to what Prof. Lawler suggests, I am perfectly fine with slapping *ness* onto any word at all. *Polyesterness* is fine with me, so is *nakedness*, so are *awwness* and *whoaness*, *getoutness* and *comeonness*.

Comment: @Cruncher, ‘fastest’ is an _inflected_ form of an adjective. Similarly, you can add the verbal ending _-ing_ on to any (non-modal) verb, but only to its uninflected root form. You can say ‘sleeping’, but you can’t just say that ‘slept’ and ‘sleeps’ are also verbs so ‘slepting’ and ‘sleepsing’ should be grammatically valid forms as well. That’s not how things work.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Onto any word? That would recursively give you an infinite number of words. As if 'x' is a word, then so is 'xness'. If 'xness' is a word, then so is 'xnessness'.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, basically any derivational suffix can be used with any word in English. The question is more whether the meaning will be transparent, which I would argue it isn’t in something like ‘comeonness’. I can think of contexts where something like that would structurally fit in, but I cannot conjure up a meaning for the word based on its constituents, even in context. As such, it fails as a proper on-the-spot derivation for me.

Comment: Cruncher: Exactly. And you are having a problem with that because...? There *is* an infinite number of words *already*, I hope you do realize that. In no small part precisely thanks to suffixes. There are in fact entire suffix chains that can be repeated ad infinitum, like *ize* and *ation*.

Comment: @Janus fair to say, but I humbly submit that you cannot conjure up a meaning for *most* words. I also submit that a funny one-off word like *comeonness* is actually more likely to be perfectly understandable in context than established, very simple, ubiquitous words such as *fidelity*, *Marxism*, *heart*, *bat*, or *sputnik*, for which you have to know the meaning beforehand.

Comment: @RegDwigнt in light of this very loose philosophy on what is and isn't a word, if one more person tries to tell me that "stupider" isn't a word, but "stupid" is, then I'll be upset.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, but those are not on-the-spot derivations, they are established words and expected to already be stored as lexemes in your mind. On-the-spot derivations are not—they rely on transparency to be understood. If I derive ‘fidelitiness’ from ‘fidelity’, it is transparent enough that anyone will understand me, even though it’s not an established word. If I derived ‘ationizeticness’ from a number of derivational suffixes, that is not the case, even though neither derivation nor resulting word is impermissible. That’s when I’d say derivation is non-productive.

Comment: Professor Emeritus John Lawler: '[D]erivational affixes do not normally apply to entire word classes like "adjective".'  Janus Bahs Jacquet: 'basically any derivational suffix can be used with any word in English.' I know who I think gets it right.

Comment: I might get slightly less hung up on whether it's actually a word, and instead on whether you understood. This talk comes to mind: https://www.ted.com/talks/erin_mckean_the_joy_of_lexicography/transcript

Of course you can take this to an absurd end, but only the Sith deal in absolutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search for *-ness* words on *onelook.com* (a portal to numerous online dictionaries) generates a list of 100 examples just between *abrasiveness* and *bitterness*. I would guess there are several thousand.

However, these are not all the adjectives in English (well, I hope not). Some adjectives have their own noun forms that do not use -*ness*, for example, the noun form of *indifferent* is *indifference*, not *indifferentness*.

You also have to distinguish between different types of adjectives. Some are participles, verb forms that can be used like adjectives, as in your example *sleeping*. These are much less likely to be amenable to a *-ness* construction.  In fact, the noun form for many participle adjectives is the gerund that has the same form as the participle, for example *running*. Similarly, as you suggest, the comparative and superlative forms of adjectives do not lend themselves to *-ness* formations.

Also some words used as adjectives are themselves nouns, such as *car* in *car factory*, or as you offer, polyester, a noun that can be used adjectivally.

In sum, you can form nouns by adding *-ness* to many, but not all adjectives.

Comment: [*Angriness*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/angriness) is in use, so adding *-ness* doesn't seem to be blocked by the existence of *angry*.

Comment: I've dredged up (?) manquéness as non-existent. Some of the following non-semantically-predicative adjectives might also not comply: next, last, previous, subsequent, preceding, further, utter, sheer, outright, main, chief, principal, mere, future, then, former, past, now? once?  intermittent ...

  potential, budding

Comment: @snailboat Good point. I changed the example.

Comment: I also think ness can be added to any adjective to form nouns. I have read it about this in word power made easy written by Norman Lewis.

Answer (score -3):

I would say -ness  is a suffix that can be added to any adjective. The corresponding German suffix -nis can also be added to verbs or nouns, e.g. zeugen or Zeuge + nis gives Zeugnis.

Astonishingly, if read backwards, English -ness gives -sen. I think it is connected with German sein (to be) and the idea of illness would be "the ill-being
(das Krank-Sein).

German zeugen means to testify or to bear testimony. So the idea of Zeugnis would be 
"something that is being testifying/being a witness" (Zeuge-Seiendes).

Marchand in his book about word-formation says: -ness forms nouns with the meaning 
"state, condition, quality of". Since Old English it has chiefly been tacked on to adjectives and participle adjectives, but in Modern English it is also used with various other bases, but not with verbs.

Comment: At least three sub-classes of adjectives contain some members that are resistant (to say the least) to accepting the -ness postfix. I can find no dictionary entries accepting the following are-they-words-or-aren't-theys?: from **Participial adjectives**: admiredness, drippingness,  friedness, neighbouringness, yawningness / **Less prototypical adjectives**:  asleepness, mereness, manquéness, onceness, then / **Classifying adjectives: biologicalness, chemicalness, nuclearness**....

Comment: Please excuse my use of the non-word 'are-they-words-or-aren't-theys?'; I'm sure it fulfils the 'can be readily understood by most anglophones' ('those strings some claim to be words but others reject as such') requirement, but not the 'widely enough used to be accepted as in the English lexicon' requirement many consider essential.